# Finding minimum value of $ \frac{x^2 +y^2}{y} $

Tags: calculus

> Finding the minimum value of $\displaystyle \frac{x^2 +y^2}{y}.$ where $x,y$ are 
>   real
>    numbers satisfying $7x^2 + 3xy + 3y^2 = 1$

Try: Equation $7x^2+3xy+3y^2=1$ represent Ellipse

with center is at origin.

So substitute $x=r\cos \alpha $ and $y=r\sin \alpha$

in $7x^2+3xy+3y^2=1$

$$3r^2+4r^2\cos^2 \alpha+3r^2\sin \alpha \cos \alpha =1$$

$$3r^2+2r^2(1+\cos 2 \alpha)+\frac{3r^2}{2}\sin 2 \alpha =1$$

$$8r^2+r^2(4\cos 2 \alpha+3\sin \alpha)=2$$

So $$r^2=\frac{2}{8+(4\cos 2 \alpha+3\sin \alpha)}$$

$$\frac{2}{8+5}=\frac{2}{13}\leq r^2\leq \frac{2}{8-5}=\frac{2}{3}$$

we have to find minimum of $$\frac{x^2+y^2}{y}=\frac{r}{\sin \alpha}$$

How can i find it, could some help me

Comment: Your multiplying the equation by $ 2 $ step is wrong. Recheck.

Comment: With this approach you have to remember that $r$ is a function of $\alpha$ ... Can you figure out the function $r(\alpha)$?

Answer (score 3):

Lagrange function is
$$L=k\, \left( 3 {{y}^{2}}+3 x y+7 {{x}^{2}}-1\right) +\frac{{{y}^{2}}+{{x}^{2}}}{y}$$
Solve system:
$$L'_x=0,\quad L'_y=0,\quad L'_k=0.$$

We get two solutions
$$k=1/4,y=-2/5,x=-1/5$$ $$k=-1/4,y=2/5,x=1/5$$

Answer:

$$f_{min}=f\left(-\frac{1}{5},-\frac{2}{5}\right)=-\frac{1}{2}$$

with CAS Maxima:

[image]

Comment: $f(2/5,-1/5)=-1<-\frac{1}{2}=f(-1/5,-2/5)$

Comment: @smcc   Solution $x=-1/5, y=-2/5$ is local minimum point. If $y\rightarrow-0$ then $f\rightarrow-\infty$

Comment: Yes, this is what my answer shows, and is the point of my comment above. The OP does not say they are looking for a local minimum (perhaps they are, but they only say "minimum" which usually(?) refers to the global minimum).

Answer (score 2):

Making $y = \lambda x$ we have

$$
\min f(x,\lambda) \ \ \mbox{s. t. }\ \ g(x,\lambda) = 0
$$

here

$$
\begin{cases}
f(x,\lambda) = \frac{1+\lambda^2}{\lambda}x\\
g(x,\lambda) = x^2(7+3\lambda+3\lambda^2)-1=0
\end{cases}
$$

this minimization problem is equivalent to

$$
\min F(\lambda) = \left(\frac{1+\lambda^2}{\lambda}\right)^2\frac{1}{7+3\lambda+3\lambda^2}
$$

and then

$$
F'(\lambda)= 0\to (1 + \lambda^2) (3 \lambda^3 + 2 \lambda^2- 9 \lambda  -14 )=(\lambda-2) (7 + 8 \lambda + 3 \lambda^2) = 0
$$

hence $\lambda = 2\to x = \pm \sqrt{\frac{1}{7+3\times 2+3\times 2^2}} = \pm\frac{1}{5}$ etc.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has no solution (assuming you are looking for a (global) minimum rather than just a local minimum). As we approach the point $(1/\sqrt{7},0)$ along the constraint curve from below the $x$-axis, the value of the function goes to $-\infty$:

The points

$$\left(\frac{\sqrt{28-75{y}^{2}}-3y}{14},y\right)$$

satisfy the constraint. We have

$$\begin{align*}f\left(\frac{\sqrt{28-75{y}^{2}}-3y}{14},y\right)&=
%\frac{65{y}^{2}+14-3y\sqrt{28-75{y}^{2}}}{98y}=
65y+\frac{1}{7y}-\frac{3}{98}\sqrt{28-75{y}^{2}}\to-\infty\end{align*}$$

as $y\to0^-$.